# Get value of custom checkbox from Gutenberg sidebar in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

In older WordPress versions I have used `post_submitbox_misc_actions`. Now with the new Gutenberg editor, I'm struggling to achieve the same functionality with my existing WordPress plugin.

So basically I just need to add a simple checkbox in the "Post & Visibility" section/block in Gutenberg that must not be pre-filled or permanently stored. I just need the information whether the checkbox has been checked or not in the (PHP) WordPress plugin to perform a simple cURL call.

I have managed to add the the checkbox to Gutenberg using an registered JS file and the following code:

```
function MyPlugin({}) {
    return el(
        PluginPostStatusInfo,
        {
            className: 'my-plugin'
        },
        el(
            CheckboxControl,
            {
                name: 'notify',
                label: __( 'Send notification' ),
            }
        )
    );
}

registerPlugin( 'my-plugin', {
    render: MyPlugin
} );
```

But how can I process/read the checkbox information in my (PHP) WordPress plugin?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you using data to fill the checkbox? Or are you using the checkbox to set the data? It sounds like you're doing the latter, but Gutenberg is built based on the former. You need to store the state somewhere and use it to set the checkbox control, but I see no state handling in your code. You need to approach this from data storage first, not checkbox first, otherwise you have a checkbox for controlling a piece of data that does not exist. Take a look at WP Data and how Gutenberg stores its internal state, and the answer will naturally fall out of there, as well as how you watn to store it

Comment: e.g. are you trying to store this value as a post meta value? If so, how do you set and get post meta in Gutenberg? Once you have that answer you're 99% of the way to solving this question. Just remember that the data produces the user interface, the UI can be thrown away and all the tags destroyed, and it could reproduce it from the data

Comment: Hi, the latter one, the user has to decide if it's checked or not (if checked a notification should be sent to an external API on a post update). So it's not necessary to store this information as the user needs to decide again on the next update. But if I understand correctly, I need to store it / use meta data? No way to get the checkbox value easily eg as $_POST['chechbox-name']?

Comment: I see, you would still need to store it via data, even if you chose not to use a persistent method such as meta. The UI is created from the data, not the other way around. Look into storing information using WP Data, and then retrieve that stored information to set the checkbox value. You can hook into the checkbox to change it, however I do not know how to send that information to WP on the post update/publish requests without it being post meta. Keep in mind you can also ask on the Gutenberg GitHub issues, right now that's by far the best place to ask these kinds of questions

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a lot of stuff is stored via WP Data that isn't sent in those requests, and rightly so. You don't need to know if a panel is open or closed to update a post. I also don't know if it's a `POST` request, or an `UPDATE` request